# Figuring out which cells neighbor a specific cell in a grid

Tags: java, c++

If you have a grid that can be different dimensions(i.e 4x6 then 10x15) how would you go about finding out what cells are near that specific cell? Is it possible to say you're in cell 15 and tell that if its a 10x10 grid that cell 15 has cells 5, 14, 16, and 25 as neighbors? Or would the fact that the grid can have many different dimensions make it impossible to have a function in C++ or Java that could on the fly figure that out?

Comment: No, if this was impossible many games and piecs of software would be impossible as well.

Comment: You can just have a list of neighbors for each cell as they are constructed...

Comment: I'm not going to edit this so the retarded people can answer my question. If you don't get it then piss off.

Answer (score 2):

Let's construct an algorithm:

Given the dimensions `m` rows*`n` columns, we have the following example grid. In this example, `m` is 2 and `n` is 3.

```
+-----+ 
|0|1|2|
+-----+
|3|4|5|
+-----+
```

Now, we can determine that the number of a cell in vertical position `a` and horizontal position `b` is `am+b`.

Since we know `m`, let's figure out a and b using modulo.

Since b is less than `m` (as we are using 0 for the first row and column as done in programming), we can say that the position of gridsquare `z` is column `z%m`, row `floor(z/m)` where `floor(` means rounding down to an integer.

You can then try adding and subtracting 1 to m and n to get the 4 neighboring squares, then calculate their numerical ID with `am+b` as shown before.